# Sniff packets using tcpdump

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I have a completely noob question. I want to see all packets that come to my computer from particular site (google.com). So I start tcpdump

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 host google.com
```

and enter `google.com` in a browser and hit enter - nothing gets captured. 
I can't figure out why it happen. 
What do I do wrong?

---

### Edit

It appeared that I was listening to the wrong interface. I had changed `eth0` to `any` and it worked. It was `ppp1` that needed listening. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Your command above works ok for me on Ubuntu. Are you sure that eth0 is the port you want to capture ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possibilities.

1- You are listening on the wrong the interface `eth0`, `eth1`, etc.

2- You did not wait enough for the packets to show up. Packets are not shown immediately unless you specify `-n` to disable name resolution.

3- You are filtering based on the wrong IP address as suggested by "Nathan Adams".

Comment: You might want to also try adding "port 80" instead of a host, at least until you can figure out what the correct IP address is.

Comment: You're right - I changed `eth0` to `any` and it worked. I figured out that it was ppp1, not eth0 that needed to be listened

Answer (score 0):

It's probably filtering the wrong address because google.com has multiple addresses.

Try something simpler like:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 host 8.8.8.8
dig google.com @8.8.8.8


11:11:01.488442 IP 192.168.128.203.45665 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 32923+ A? google.com. (28)
11:11:01.512304 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > 192.168.128.203.45665: 32923 6/0/0 A iy-in-f105.1e100.net,[|domain]
```